# How to convert a paid app to a free app with in-app purchasing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

First I had created one app, which I uploaded into the Play store with some price, and I got some downloads. Now I want to add in-app purchases to my app and I want make my app free.

If I update my .apk (with in-app purchase) into the Play store then it will send notification to the users who have purchased my app.

If they are updated then it will show in-app purchases also so they have to purchase some modules.

So I want to set in-app purchases as active for users who have purchased my app.

Is there a specific process for accomplishing this?

Comment: its long procedure to be described here... order me a gig, i will do it :p

Comment: Hey tell me the procedure please if you know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can make a paid app be free**

```
Is there a specific process for accomplishing this?
```

No, their is no official way to do this, Because In-App you have to add items on google play and its show to every user util he/she pay for that In-App Item.

but you can handle by your own way.

Like if user already pay then you have to hide in-app(or whatever your app flow) for that perticular user and enable that future for them.
So no need to pay again for same

in sort you can handle by JAVA code(because you have list of paid user)

If app have same package and current version is new then installed then its update app(make sure both version are signed with same certificate/keystore)

**Important:**
If you change an app from Paid to Free and save the change, the change is permanent. Once changed to free, the app can't be changed back to a paid app. If you want to charge again for a paid app that you’ve changed to a free app, you would need to create a new app with a new package name and set a price for the new app.

[Android Developer Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to add vending inapp billing files in your package, then in manifest you have to give permission. thats from application side, now you have to configure product id and licence key. Below is very useful link which i also had applied, Hope it works for you too :)....

[Sample Project](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) && [configuration](https://help.gamesalad.com/gamesalad-cookbook/7-using-pro-features/7-03-adding-in-app-purchases-iap/7-03-2-setting-up-iap-for-google-play/)

Comment: is It work for the users who has already my app that will not ask in-app purchases.I had added what they are given in this tutorial http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial                     my question is when i upload this in-app purchase .apk is it will update in already installed devices please check once

Answer (score 0):

My little contribution is that setting the app to use in-app purchases is in the Content Rating (of all places) There is one checkbox!!! Lost an hour at least on this.